# Cython print() outputs before C printf(), even when placed afterwards

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to pick up Cython.

```
import counter

cdef public void increment():
    counter.increment()

cdef public int get():
    return counter.get()

cdef public void say(int times):
    counter.say(times)
```

This is the "glue code" I'm using to call functions from counter.py, a pure Python source code file. It's laid out like this:

```
count = 0

def increment():
    global count

    count += 1

def get():
    global count

    return count

def say(times):
    global count

    print(str(count) * times)
```

I have successfully compiled and run this program. The functions work fine. However, a very strange thing occured when I tested this program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();

    // The following two lines add the current working directory
    // to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. This allows us
    // to import Python modules in this directory.
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

    PyInit_glue();

    // Tests
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        increment();
    }

    int x = get();
    printf("Incremented %d times\n", x);

    printf("The binary representation of the number 42 is");
    say(3);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the program to produce this output:

```
Incremented 10 times
The binary representation of the number 42 is
101010
```

However, it prints this:

```
Incremented 10 times
101010
The binary representation of the number 42 is
```

But if I change the line

```
printf("The binary representation of the number 42 is");
```

to

```
printf("The binary representation of the number 42 is\n");
```

then the output is corrected.

This seems strange to me. I understand that if I want to print the output of a Python function, I might just as well return it to C and store it in a variable, and use C's printf() rather than the native Python print(). But I would be very interested to hear the reason this is happening. After all, the printf() statement is reached before the say() statement (I double checked this in gdb just to make sure). Thanks for reading.

Comment: My first thought is that you might need a statement like `fflush(stdout);` in there. But it could also just be an issue with no newline on what "counts" as the last statement. See the discussion here, apparently C does funky things with no newline at (or near?) the last statement. I'm a little unclear on how you're say function shows a binary representation though. https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/629409-fflush-stdout

Comment: @EricCarlsen I was thinking the same. On most machines, newlines `fflush` by default, but otherwise you have to do it yourself. See `man setvbuf`.